# Finding a bijective function from $A$ to $B$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Find a bijective function from $A := \left\{ f\colon \mathbb N \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)\right\}$ to $B := \left\{g\colon \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \{0, 1\}\right\}$.

I have been trying to solve this one for over an hour without success. Any help?

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$? Functions or sets?

Comment: The description of $A$ and $B$ is not clear. Is $A$ the set of all functions from natural numbers to its power set?

Comment: @AnuragA: $A$ is the set of all functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$. In some traditions, the preferred notation for this is $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)^{\mathbb N}$ rather than $\mathbb N\to\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, but it is the same set. Similarly you may know $B$ as $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N\times\mathbb N}$.

Comment: I lack training in transfinite arithmetic, but it looks as though $$|A| = \aleph_1^{\aleph_0}$$ and $$|B| = \aleph_1$$ Are these cardinal numbers equal?

Answer (score 5):

How about $$U \colon A \to B , \quad U(f)(x,y) = 1 \Longleftrightarrow y \in f(x),$$
with inverse $$V \colon B \to A, \quad V(g)(x) = \{ y \mid g(x,y) = 1\}.$$

Added: Nothing special about $\mathbb{N}$; it works for any set $S$. If one thinks of $\mathcal{P}(S)$ as $S\to \{0,1\}$, then the statement is equivalent to $$S \to (S\to \{0,1\}) \simeq (S\times S) \to \{0,1\} ,$$
or, in the power notation,
$$\left( \{0,1\}^S\right)^S \simeq (\{0,1\})^{S\times S}$$

This is a particular case of the more general result that $(X^Y)^Z \simeq X^{Y\times Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to elaborate a bit more on the nice answer of Catalin Zara. Namely, how can one possibly come up with those functions? For this it is helpful to recall what the power set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is

$$\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) = \{ M\subseteq \mathbb{N} \}.$$

How can one construct a subset of $\mathbb{N}$? For every natural number we can either include it in our set or not. Thus, we can encode every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ as a function $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \{ 0, 1\}$ deciding for every element of $\mathbb{N}$ wheter it belongs to the subset or not. More formally, the following is a bijection

$$\phi: \ \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow \{f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \{0,1\}\}, \ M \mapsto \phi(M)$$

where $\phi(M)(n)=1$ if $n$ lies in $M$ and $\phi(M)(n)=0$ if it doesn't lie in $M$. The inverse map is given by

$$ \phi^{-1}: \{f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \{0,1\}\} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \ f \mapsto \{ n\in \mathbb{N}: f(n)=1 \}.$$

In the your question we want to encode functions $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. Using the bijection of the previous paragraph we can think of the set $f(n)$ as being the function $\phi(f(n)): \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0 ,1 \}$. Letting $n\in \mathbb{N}$ vary we get a function $\phi(f(\cdot))(\cdot): \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0,1 \}$. This is precisely the function $U$ given in Catalin Zara's answer. Namely

$$ U(f)(n)(m) = \phi(f(n))(m).$$

We get its inverse function $V$ be similar reasoning. If we have a function $g: \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ and fix some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then we get a function $g(n, \cdot): \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \{0,1\}$. But this defines a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Applying $\phi^{-1}$ yields the inverse function of $U$ denoted by $V$ in Catalin Zara's answer. I.e.

$$ V(g)(n)= \phi^{-1}(g(n,\cdot)).$$

As mentioned in Catalin Zara's answer, this construction is completely general and does not depend on $\mathbb{N}$. To get the argument for a general set $S$ one simply replaces every $\mathbb{N}$ by $S$.

Comment: Thank you for the nice words.

Comment: @CatalinZara Don't mention it. Your answer is brief, complete and in full generality. It deserves every praise it gets.

Comment: @user401516 You can accept Catalin Zara's answer to indicate that you question has been fully answered and to reward her with some reputation. This will you even bring the 'Scholar' badge :)